# Twitter Bootstrap - Horizontal Description & Inline Lists not working but everything else is?

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble implementing the following code into my wordpress blog. I've installed twitter bootstrap plug-ins but these tags still won't work:

```
<ul class="inline">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

And this as well:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>...</dt>
  <dd>...</dd>
</dl>
```

Everything else on bootstrap appears to work but these tags don't. Any reasons that come to mind?

(For example, the address tag works, the `<p class="lead">...</p>` works, but just the above two do not work).

For the `<ul>`, I just get a normal multi-line list.

For the `<dl>`, I don't get the horizontal description list; the description always appears under the title even with a short description.

Comment: Hi Mark, its the css that is causing this issue. Can you firebug some css being picked up and put a fiddle for it so we know what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebug or fiddles. 

The code samples I gave are straight from: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#code

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the CSS rules for these elements are defined by Bootstrap, but are then overridden by another CSS file. Use a developer tool (install Firebug extension if you use Firefox) by right-clicking on you list, and select "Inspect element". There will be a list of the CSS properties declared for the element